# Web Service URL for a ESXi Server

Tags: sdk, vmware, vsphere, esx

I am trying to run the Java samples from Vsphere Web Services SDK and for many of them it requires URL of the Web Service.
What is it for an ESXI Server and How to find it?

I have already tried with url as "https://esxiIP/sdk/vimService.wsdl"

Following Error occurs whenever I am trying to run a sample

..........................................................

ERROR: could not connect: login fault : The server sent HTTP status code 400: Bad Request

com.vmware.connection.SsoConnection$SSOLoginException: could not connect: login fault : The server sent HTTP status code 400: Bad Request
        at com.vmware.connection.SsoConnection.connect(SsoConnection.java:250)
        at com.vmware.connection.ConnectedVimServiceBase.connect(ConnectedVimServiceBase.java:118)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vmware.common.samples.registry.ActionReference.invoke(ActionReference.java:80)
        at com.vmware.common.samples.registry.ActionReference.invokeAction(ActionReference.java:65)
        at com.vmware.common.samples.registry.ActionReference.action(ActionReference.java:47)
        at com.vmware.common.samples.registry.SampleReference.run(SampleReference.java:96)
        at com.vmware.common.samples.registry.SampleReference.run(SampleReference.java:88)
        at com.vmware.common.Main.run(Main.java:282)
        at com.vmware.common.Main.sampleSwitching(Main.java:254)
        at com.vmware.common.Main.registeredSample(Main.java:169)
        at com.vmware.common.Main.main(Main.java:121)
............................................................................

I think this is occurring because of malformed URL only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be https://esxiIP/sdk for the root URL.

Additional information can be found in the SDK programming guide: https://code.vmware.com/docs/6611/vmware-vsphere-web-services-sdk-programming-guide#/doc/GUID-943BE167-B018-4FDD-AC62-D629E09BF316.html

Comment: Thanks for replying Kyle! I was able to solve the error by adding "--basic-connection basic-connection" to the command..but I don't understand the main reason behind this.